# Radgridview select only one detail row

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radgrid

In my silverlight application I have a page with a radgridview,
this radgridview has another control as RowDetailsTemplate.

In this RowDetailsTemplate is another radgridview with another controls as RowDetailsTemplate.
this RowDetailsTemplate also has a radgridview.

All the gridviews have several bindings to my ViewModel (I've used MVVM)

The hierarchy is like this:

```
 - RadGridView
      - RadGridView (in fact a seperate control with a gridview, setup as rowdetailstemplate on the parent gridview)
           -RadGridView (in fact a seperate control with a gridview, setup as rowdetailstemplate on the parent gridview)
```

In my setup you can have one row selected for every grid / detail grid.

This means you can visually have 1 to N rows selected in the entire grid.
This looks pretty chaotic and isn't very user friendly.

My question:

What is the best way to change this so only one row can be selected, instead of 1 to N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it would be the desired way.. But you could do something like this...

```
    Private Sub AllGrids_ItemClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) _
    Handles grd1.ItemCommand, grd2.ItemCommand, grd3.ItemCommand
    dim gridSelected as New RadGrid 
    gridSelected = sender
    If e.CommandName = "RowClick" Then
       if gridSelected.ID = grd1.ID then
          For i As Integer = 0 To grdMenu.Items.Count - 1
            If grd2.Items(i).Selected Then
                grd2.Items(i).Selected = False
            End If
           Next
           For i As Integer = 0 To grdMenu.Items.Count - 1
            If grd3.Items(i).Selected Then
                grd3.Items(i).Selected = False
            End If
           Next
       end if
    End If
    '' Do this again for each of the other grids.
End Sub
```

Basically you would loop through the grids that didn't cause the event to deselect everything.

Comment: This solution seems workable, I had hoped to find something more MVVM like, but this will definately do.